# Angular Filter for returning true false from api?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-filters, angular-components, angular-controller

So i am trying to display, weather a user is active or not active. The data comes via an api in Boolean form. So it will simply say user is true or user is false .I want to show 'Active' if data returns true, 'Not Active' if user return false.Solution i did was a simple if else that does the job, but this is heavily reused through out the app and i want to make an angular filter to do this task.
I am a beginner in angular and java script and haven't created a filter before.

this is my if else and showing it in html
this i how i want to use eventuatlly

```
<label>{{ $ctrl.myValu | truefalse}}</label>
```

```js
  $onInit = () => {
        let self = this;

        this.siUser.current().then((userData) => {
            let actingAsTenant = userData.user.apikey;

            if (actingAsTenant) {

                self.siTenant.current().then((tenant) => {
                    self.tenant = tenant;
                   
                   ///starts
                    if (self.tenant.active == true) {
                        self.tenant.active = 'Active'
                    }
                    else if (self.tenant.active == false){
                        self.tenant.active = 'Not Active'
                    }
                    //end
                    
                }, (err) => {
                    self.siAlertDialog.error(err.data.message)
                })

            }
        }, (err) => {
            self.siAlertDialog.error('Error rendering tenant details');
        });
    }
```

```html
<strong>{{$ctrl.tenant.active}}</strong>
```

Comment: i want to create an angular filter, so its reusable my code is working above. so i want to create a filter for true or false , eventually look something like this <label>{{ $ctrl.myValu | truefalse}}</label>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
For this you need to create filter. Try to with the given code

<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>

        <title>Ristorante Con Fusion: Menu</title>
          <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>

      <div ng-app="myapp" ng-controller="userController" >
      {{ myValu | truefalse }}

        <script>
   var app = angular.module('myapp', []);

   app.filter('truefalse', function(){
        return function(text){
          return text ? "Active" : "Not Active";
        }
      })
app.controller('userController', function($scope) {
      $scope.myValu = true;
});
        </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: i want to create a angular filter! ,my code is working.

Comment: some thing like this <label>{{ $ctrl.myValu | truefalse}}</label>

Comment: For this you need to create filter. Try to with the updated code

Comment: thank you , that worked. Sorry i am little confused with return text ? "Active" : "Not Active"; how is the filter reading  true or false since we are not saying if  true say active else not active. Is the es6 (ternary) Operator automatically assumes if true first string (active) if false second string (not active)

Answer (score 0):

You can use Ternary Operator:

**JS**

```
///starts
      self.tenant.active == true ? 'Active' : 'Not Active';
//end
```

**OR**

**In Angular Expression**

```
<strong>{{ $ctrl.tenant.active ? 'Active' : 'Not Active' }}</strong>
```

Comment: my code is working , i want to create an angualr filter so i can just the filter instead of coding. something like this <label>{{ $ctrl.myValu | truefalse}}</label>

Comment: Goes same for filter (function as a filter): `$scope.truefalse= function (item) { 
    return item ? 'Active' : 'Not Active';
};`

**OR**
`app.filter('truefalse', function() {
    return function(item) {
             return item ? 'Active' : 'Not Active';
   }
});`